# A question from a seasoned user should be worth more than a question from newbies

Tags: feature-request, reputation

More than a question, this is a suggestion, I've been told this is the right place to post it, so here I am.

My suggestion is, as the title says: **A question from a seasoned user should be worth more than a question from newbies**, or in other words, the point system should consider the reputation of the user asking a question.

I contribute to Stack Overflow for software development topics.

I just feel like there are too many (mostly novice) users asking the same 'basic' questions over and over again, making evident they haven't even tried. They ask experts to review their code (often a copy paste from a tutorial) and find errors (often just typos) or questions that are obvious evidence of laziness.

On the other hand, to increase their reputation, users tend to answer more of these 'easy to solve' questions than the **hard questions posted by experienced programmers**, because they earn the same points, and the hard questions remain often unsolved. This affects me because when I submit a hard question, many times it remains unnoticed, in favor of the easy questions.

Comment: Just so you know; downvotes on meta can indicate disagreement rather than your question being inappropriate. Just got a feeling it may be relevant

Comment: I wish to delete the question. If someone can help flagging it for deletion.

Comment: @Merlevede it has upvoted answers, so I am not sure if it's going to happen. That being said, don't take downvotes on meta personally.

Answer (score 21):

I disagree. A question's value cannot be determined by a user's rep.

Just because someone doesn't have rep (or has less rep than you) on SO doesn't mean they aren't a good programmer and can't ask a good question.

I've also seen bad/basic questions asked by high-rep users because in the certain tag, they are a "newbie".

This is similar to other meta posts about weighted questions, like [Adding Weights to Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106363/adding-weights-to-questions).

Also, I would mark this as "status completed"... due to the Bounty program there is already a way to reward difficult questions.

Answer (score 9):

You are supposed to vote on the question, not on the user. If a new member asks a good question, it should be equally rewarded. New members also ask good, interesting, hard to answer questions, and handicapping them would be simply unfair.

Besides, high-rep users can set up bounties on their questions to gather attention. Use them if you think your questions pass unnoticed.